# Labels en PyPlot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

No estaría entiendo como asociar los names a estrellas_pais en el gráfico. Alguna idea de como asociarlos?

Probé esto:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
estrellas_pais = data.groupby(['nationality'])['overall'].apply(lambda x: (x>=90).sum())

# Crear el circulo adentro del chart
names = data.groupby(['nationality'])['overall'].apply(lambda x: (x>=90).sum())

my_circle = plt.Circle( (0,0), 0.7, color='white')

# Custom wedges
plt.pie(estrellas_pais, labels=names, wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 8, 'edgecolor' : 'white' })
p = plt.gcf()
p.gca().add_artist(my_circle)
plt.title('Selecciones con jugadores estrella')
plt.show()
```

Pero claro, se me asocian numeros a los labels cuando realmente lo que estoy buscando es que País corresponde a ese numero. Muchas gracias

Comment: Basicamente tengo una dataframe de jugadores de futbol, mi idea es saber cuantos jugadores por pais, se encuentran arriba de 90 de media

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el mínimo código necesario y los datos (Como texto, no como imagen) para reproducir el problema.